# Переход по меткам в коде?

Tags: android, android-studio

В 1с была такая фитча нажимаешь комбинацию клавиш и там где находится в коде курсор ставится метка, далее программируешь ставишь другую метку и по нажатии комбинации клавиш в коде можно перемещаться по этим меткам. 
Есть что то подобное в Android Studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Меню *Navigate -> Bookmarks*:

или

- <kbd>F11</kbd> - поставить\снять метку.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> - вывести список меток и перейти к нужной.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> - поставить метку с мнемоникой\снять метку

Так же есть переход к предыдущей\следующей метке, но горячие клавиши по умолчанию за этими действиями не закреплены (доступны только из меню) - их можно назначить самому

Comment: Век живи - век учись! Не знал!